# How to distinguish between actors in a use case?

Tags: modeling, use-case

Having a use case that is slightly different for either actor, how should this be captured in the use case specification?

Answer (score 0):

An example should be helpful, but if I correctly understood your question you just have to associate use case with the right actor...

Answer (score 0):

Extract the differences to a sub-usecases. For example, it can be something like this (of course, the actual diagram may differ and should correspond to the actual context):
[image]